# Dojo view not found error

Tags: dojo, xpages

My development server has no trouble with my first mobile app in 853. However, when I try to use it in a second database, with different views, I can never open the underlying documents in the view. I get the typical error:

```
dojox.mobile.view#performTransition: destination view not found: null
```

My mobile page is m_milestoneList and I've got the page prefix set in xsp.properties:

```
xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix=m_
```

I can't see where my mistake is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
    window.scrollTo(0,0); // reset in case prev not scrolled var
    nPageH = $(document).height(); var nViewH = window.outerHeight;
    if (nViewH > nPageH) { nViewH -= 250;
    $('BODY').css('height',nViewH + 'px'); } window.scrollTo(0,1); }

    });
</script>
<xe:singlePageApp id="singlePageApp1"
    selectedPageName="milestoneList">
    <xe:appPage id="appPage1" pageName="milestoneList">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="Milestone List"></xe:djxmHeading>
        <xe:dataView id="dataView1" pageName="#milestoneDetails"
            collapsibleDetail="true">
            <xe:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView var="milestoneView"
                    viewName="MilestoneOwner">
                </xp:dominoView>
            </xe:this.data>
            <xe:this.summaryColumn>
                <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnName="Subject"></xe:viewSummaryColumn>
            </xe:this.summaryColumn>
            <xe:this.categoryColumn>
                <xe:viewCategoryColumn columnName="TAT_ADvisor"></xe:viewCategoryColumn>
            </xe:this.categoryColumn>
        </xe:dataView>
    </xe:appPage>
    <xe:appPage id="milestoneDetails" pageName="milestoneDetails"
        resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading2" label="Details"
            back="Back" moveTo="milestoneList">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoDocument var="milestoneDocument"
                    formName="Milestone">
                </xp:dominoDocument>
            </xp:this.data>
            <xp:table>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="Acronym:"
                            id="acronym_Label1" for="acronym1">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:inputText value="#{milestoneDocument.Acronym}" id="acronym1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:appPage>
</xe:singlePageApp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code in a test database and it works.
Have you enabled extension library in the new database?
I have also got a similir problem when I tried to navigate to a page that didn't exist as a PageName in the mobile application.

Comment: Yes, I do have the extension library enabled. Good to know the problem is not the code. I just have to make a list of all the settings and make sure I've done them all. Very odd.

Comment: Try a project clean. And copy the content to a new xpage.

Comment: I was using the URL for the production database while I was changing the code in the development database. Doh!